# Mongoose model creates a plural database name automatically

Tags: mongodb

I created the mongoose model below :

```
Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', movieSchema);
```

But in the terminal I can only access the entries by `db.movies`.
It seems mongoose created that DB name `movies` on its own.

What's the logic behind it? And how can I know what's the db names for other models I create?